# PHP db2_fetch_assoc & db2_fetch_both

Tags: php, db2

I'm successfully connecting to the database, and successfully pulling data and displaying it using db2_fetch_array and db2_fetch_both. The code below works just fine

```
$file="m03slsd0";
$file=db2_escape_string($file);
$query="SELECT slgrpn,slfrkn,slftyp,slfsze,slpqty,slpwht,slentp,slkplt FROM HUTALIB.$file";
$quepre=db2_prepare($conn,$query);
$quexe=db2_execute($quepre);

while($row=db2_fetch_both($quepre))
{
$det=$row[0];
if($det!='')
{
printf($det."</br>");
}
}
```

The problem comes up when i'm changing the index to column name in db2_fetch_assoc() or db2_fetch_array() - the code below prints nothing.

```
while($row=db2_fetch_both($quepre))
{
$det=$row['slgrpn'];
if($det!='')
{
printf($det."</br>");
}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What do the results contain? Do you get a database error? Is error reporting activated? Does `$row['slgrpn']` actually contain a value?

Comment: $row['slgrpn'] should contain the value $row[0] contains. I don't recieve any error, furthermore, the only problem is there's not output while there shoold be output becuase as i said before, $row[0] contains a value which is successfully printed through the first while.

Comment: Well, *does* it contain anything? Because if it doesn't, nothing will be output.

Comment: This one works just fine :
while($row=db2_fetch_both($quepre))
{
$det=$row[0];
if($det!='')
{
printf($det."</br>");
}
}

Altough this one prints nothing, while it should print exactly what the previous while loop printed
while($row=db2_fetch_both($quepre))
{
$det=$row['slgrpn'];
if($det!='')
{
printf($det."</br>");
}
}

Comment: Ah, I see now. That's different, sorry. Still, test outputs will help. What does a `print_r($row)` show?

Comment: I've tried running
while($row=db2_fetch_both($quepre))
{
print_r($row);
}

And that's part of the output I recieved
 Array ( [SLGRPN] => 12626 [0] => 12626 [SLFRKN] => 2298 [1] => 2298 [SLFTYP] => [2] => [SLFSZE] => [3] => [SLPQTY] => 36 [4] => 36 [SLPWHT] => 313.0 [5] => 313.0 [SLENTP] => 10.00 [6] => 10.00 [SLKPLT] => Ñî [7] => Ñî ) Array ( [SLGRPN] => 12627 [0] => 12627 [SLFRKN] => 1722 [1] => 1722 [SLFTYP] => [2] => [SLFSZE] => XL [3] => XL [SLPQTY] => 391 [4] => 391 [SLPWHT] => 1996.0 [5] => 1996.0 [SLENTP]

Answer (score 1):

> Array ( [SLGRPN] => 12626 ...

Array keys are case sensitive you you will need to use

```
$det=$row['SLGRPN'];
```

not sure why the field names get turned into uppercase - it might be a characteristic of db2.

Comment: It is indeed a characteristic of DB2.

Answer (score 1):

DB2 identifiers are case-insensitive by default, and will use/return uppercase field names, unless your columns are defined within double quotes (same applies for table names):

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( bar integer, "baz" integer );
```

Querying this table:

```
SELECT bar, "baz" FROM foo;
```

... in PHP would return something like:

```
Array (
    [BAR] => something
    [baz] => something   
)
```

So you'd have to do:

```
echo $array['BAR'];
echo $array['baz'];
```

To remove any ambiguity, you can change your queries:

```
SELECT BAR FROM FOO;
```

...or define all fields and table names with double quotes:

```
SELECT "bar", "baz" FROM "foo"
```